# SQlite update is not working when switching between views in iOS

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

I have a Favorites view, that loads data from an sqlite database. It loads entry into cells obviously.

The Favorites view class is named FavReal. I have enabled a canEditRowAtIndexPath with the action of deleting the entry from the database and removing it from the table View. It works fine! and also i have a clear all favorites button that removes all entry correctly.

Now, if i click on a cell, it takes me to another View called Details22 view. In this view i get the details of the selected cell and it works.

Now after clicking on an entry and going back to the Favorites View. If I try to delete an entry either by swipe gesture or by clear all button. It doesn't work :S no errors no nothing it just won't remove it from the database, and just remove it instantly from the table view.

Here are my codes.

***/*  FavReal.m */***

```
//
//  FavReal.m
//  AuthorsApp
//
//  Created by georges ouyoun on 8/16/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "FavReal.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "Author.h" 
#import "Details22.h"
#import "AuthorVC.h"
@interface FavReal ()

@end

@implementation FavReal
@synthesize textLabel2;
@synthesize theFav;
@synthesize author; 
NSString *authorNAme;
NSString *authorNAme3 , *authorNAme4;
NSString *authorFav;
NSString *PathDB;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"entered the cellForRowAtIndexPath");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"FavoritesCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
            NSLog(@"Break before the if");
    if (cell2 == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Entered the nil cell 1 ");
        cell2= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        NSLog(@"Entered the nil cell 2 ");
    }

    Author *author8 = [self.theFav objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"Author initialized");
    cell2.textLabel.text = author8.title;
    NSLog(@"This is the author8.title variable %@" , author8.title);
    NSLog(@"Cell2 is initialized");
 //   NSString *cellName = cell2.textLabel.text;

 //   [theFav release];
        return cell2;

}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
//    [self.tableView cell];
    NSLog(@"§§§§§§§§§§§§§ VIew will appear phase 1 §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§");

    [self authorList2];
    [self.tableView reloadData] ;
    NSLog(@"§§§§§§§§§§§§§ VIew will appear §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§");
   [self viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
      NSLog(@"§§§§§§§§§§§§§ ViewDidLoad §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§");
    UIBarButtonItem *nextButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Clear All Favorites"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered

                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(deleteSomeStuff)];

    [[self navigationItem] setLeftBarButtonItem:nextButton];

    [nextButton release], nextButton = nil;

    [self authorList2];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{

    NSLog(@"§§§§§§§§§§§§§ ViewDid UN-Load §§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§");

    [self setTextLabel2:nil];
    [ClearBu release];
    ClearBu = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
#warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
#warning Incomplete method implementation.
    int rowCount;

     rowCount = theFav.count;
    return rowCount;
}

-(NSMutableArray *) authorList2{

    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSLog(@"1");
    theFav = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:1000000];

    @try {
        NSLog(@"1 alpha:");

        BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:PathDB];
        NSLog(@"1 gamma");
        if(!success)
        {
            NSLog(@"2");
            NSLog(@"Cannot locate database file '%@'.", PathDB);
        }
        NSLog(@"Success");
        if(!(sqlite3_open([PathDB UTF8String], &db2) == SQLITE_OK))
        {
            NSLog(@"3");
            NSLog(@"An error has occured: %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));

        }

        NSLog(@"Database opened");
        // const char *sql = "SELECT F_Keyword FROM wordss";  
        const char *sql2 = "SELECT Name FROM Fav";

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement2;
        if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, sql2, -1, &sqlStatement2, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
        }else{
            while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement2)==SQLITE_ROW) {
              //  NSLog(@"Probleme not with the query but in here!!");
                Author * author2 = [[Author alloc] init];
                //author2.fav = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement2,2)];
                author2.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement2,0)];

               // authorFav=author2.title;              
                [theFav addObject:author2];

            }
        }
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
    }
    @finally {

        return theFav;
    }
}


-(void)deleteSomeStuff{
    NSLog(@"Delete Button Clicked");
    @try {
     //   NSLog(@"This is the authorName2 variable %@",authorNAme2);

        sqlite3_stmt *compiled_statement1;

        if(sqlite3_open([PathDB UTF8String], &db2) == SQLITE_OK) {

            NSString *formatedSql = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM Fav"];

            const char *sql = [formatedSql UTF8String];
            NSLog(@" !!!!!!!! In the middle of it !!!!!!!!!!!!");
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(db2, sql, -1, &compiled_statement1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) {
                NSLog(@"!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!ERRRRROOOOOOORRRRRRRRR!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");

            }

            NSLog(@"This is the query %@",formatedSql);


            int success = sqlite3_step(compiled_statement1);

            if (success != SQLITE_ERROR) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully Deleted!");
                sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(db2);
            }

            if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, sql, -1, &compiled_statement1, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            {
                NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));

            }else{

                NSLog(@"Got in the else tag where pictures should change ");

                while (sqlite3_step(compiled_statement1)!=SQLITE_OK) {

                    NSLog(@"Got in the while tag");
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }

       // NSArray *arr;
        [self.theFav removeAllObjects]; 
        [self.tableView reloadData];

        }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {

        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db2);
    }

}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if(editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        @try{
            if(!(sqlite3_open([PathDB UTF8String], &db2) == SQLITE_OK))
            {
                NSLog(@"3");
               // NSLog(@"Could not open Db2", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));

            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"Db2 is opened");
            }
            NSIndexPath *indPath7= [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]; 
            UITableViewCell *cell7 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indPath7]; 
            NSString *cellText7 = cell7.textLabel.text;

          //  NSLog(@"§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§§ This is the cell text §§§§§§§§§§" , cellText3);
            sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement7;
            NSString *titleString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row] autorelease];

            //const char *sql3 = ["DELETE FROM Fav WHERE rowid = '%@'" , titleString]  ;

            NSString *formatedSql3 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"DELETE FROM Fav WHERE Name = '%@'" ,cellText7];
           // const char *formatedSql3 = [@"DELETE FROM Fav WHERE rowid = '%@'",titleString];

            NSLog(@"This is the DELETE Query %@", formatedSql3);
            const char *sql3 = [formatedSql3 UTF8String];
            NSLog(@"This is the titleString Variable %@ " , titleString);

            if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, sql3, -1, &sqlStatement7, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
        {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
        }
            else{

                int successS = sqlite3_step(sqlStatement7);
                if (successS != SQLITE_DONE) {
                    NSLog(@"An error Has occured during the delete of the specific record");
                }
                else{

                    NSLog(@"Update Database successfull!");
                }
            }
        }    
                @catch (NSException *exception) {
                    NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
                }

                @finally {
                    //sqlite3_finalize(sql);
                  //  sqlite3_close(db2);
                    //return theFav;
                }
            [self.theFav removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSIndexPath *indPath3 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row inSection:0]; 
    UITableViewCell *cell3 = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indPath3]; 
    NSString *cellText3 = cell3.textLabel.text;

  //  NSLog(@"This is at first : %@" , authorNAme);
  //   NSString *titleString2 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Element row number :  %d",indexPath.row] autorelease];
    NSLog(@"This is the showDetailsForIndexPath");

    Details22 * vc4 = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Details22"];
    //FavReal* author;
    NSLog(@"This is the showDetailsForIndexPath 2");

    @try{
            if(sqlite3_open([PathDB UTF8String], &db2) == SQLITE_OK) {

        NSString *titleString3 = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Element row number :  %d",indexPath.row] autorelease];
        NSLog(@"This is the row number chosen %@",titleString3);

       NSString *formatedSql333 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Select * from Sheet1 where field3 = '%@'" , cellText3 ];
                const char *formatedSql3333 = [formatedSql333 UTF8String];

        NSLog(@"This is the SQLite Approriate Query %@",formatedSql333);

        sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement3;

        NSString *SearchedItem = cellText3;
        NSLog(@"This is the SearchedITem Variable %@" , SearchedItem);

        if(sqlite3_prepare(db2, formatedSql3333, -1, &sqlStatement3, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
            NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
    }else{

     while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement3)!=SQLITE_ERROR) {

         NSLog(@"Entered the While tag");   
         NSString *SearchedItem = cellText3;
         NSLog(@"This is the SearchedITem Variable %@" , SearchedItem);


                Author * author3 = [[Author alloc] init];
         NSLog(@" Debug 1  ");

                author3.name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3,2)];
                  NSLog(@" Debug 2  ");

                NSLog(@"This is the author.name in the FavReal %@" , author3.name);

                author3.title = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3,3)];
         NSLog(@"This is the author.TITLE in the FavReal %@" , author3.title);

                author3.genre = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *) sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement3, 6)];
         NSLog(@"This is the author.GENRE in the FavReal %@" , author3.genre);
         NSLog(@"This is the authorName before %@", authorNAme);
         NSLog(@"This is the authorName2 before %@", authorNAme2);
         authorNAme = author3.genre;
         authorNAme2 = author3.name;

         NSLog(@"This is the authorName after %@", authorNAme);
         NSLog(@"This is the authorName2 after %@", authorNAme2);

         NSLog(@"Before the break");
         NSLog(@"Before the animation part");
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc4 animated:true];   
         NSLog(@"Passed the should animate part");

         break;
         NSLog(@"After the break");
     }     
               }
    }
    }

    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"Problem with prepare statement:  %@", sqlite3_errmsg(db2));
    }
    @finally {
        sqlite3_close(db2);
        NSLog(@"The database should NOT be closed here");
    }
}

- (UITableViewCellAccessoryType)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryTypeForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    //return UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
    return UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [self tableView:tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [theFav release];
    [self release];
    [textLabel2 release];
    [textLabel2 release];
    [ClearBu release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)ClearButtonAction:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clear Button is Clicked");
}
@end
```

***/* Details22.m */***

```
//
//  Details.m
//  AuthorsApp
//
//  Created by georges ouyoun on 7/17/12.
//  Copyright (c) 2012 __MyCompanyName__. All rights reserved.
//

#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Details22.h"
#import "Author.h"
#import "AuthorVC.h"
#import <sqlite3.h>
#import "FavReal.h"
//#import "MTPopupWindow.h"


@interface Details22 ()

@end

@implementation Details22
//@synthesize Favo;
@synthesize text2;
@synthesize WebV2;
@synthesize labelText;
@synthesize selectedAuthors;
@synthesize author , infoRequest;
NSUInteger textFontSize2 = 20;
NSString *PathDB; 
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"In the viewDidLoad this is the current value of the textFontSize %d" , textFontSize2);

    NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                             <html>\
                             <body>\
                             <p dir='rtl' style = 'font-size:40px;'> %@ </p>\
                             </body>\
                             </html>",authorNAme];


    [self.WebV2 setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.WebV2 loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

    self.text2.text = authorNAme2;

    /* ////////////////////////////////////////////         This is where the label text APPearsssssssss       ///////////////////////////          */

    NSLog(@"Everything is ok now !");

}
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    //  [self setLabelText:nil];
    NSLog(@"U have entered view did unload in Details22");

    //[FavReal initialize];

    [self setText2:nil];

    [self setWebV2:nil];

    [sizeFontFromStepper release];
    sizeFontFromStepper = nil;
    [super viewDidUnload];

    //[self setLabelText:Nil];
    //[AuthorVC load];

    //[self release];
   // NSLog(@" FAvReal should have been initialised ");
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{ 
    NSLog(@"U have entered the viewWillAppear tag");
}

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{

      NSLog(@"This is the view will disappear tag in Details22");

}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [labelText release];

    [text2 release];
   // [fontStep release];
    [WebV2 release];
    [sizeFontFromStepper release];
   // [sizeFontFromStepper release];
    [super dealloc];
}

-(void)loadHTMLString:(int)textFontSize2
{
    NSString * htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\
                             <html>\
                             <body>\
                             <p dir='rtl' style = 'font-size:%dpx;'> %@ </p>\
                             </body>\
                             </html>",textFontSize2,authorNAme];

    NSLog(@"This is the loadHTMLString function with a textFonSize of %d" , textFontSize2);

    //[self.WebV setScalesPageToFit:YES];
    [self.WebV2 loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

}
- (IBAction)loadHtmlNewFontSize:(int)textFontSize2 {

    textFontSize2 = sizeFontFromStepper.value;

    [self loadHTMLString:textFontSize2];

    NSLog(@"This is textFontSize %d" , textFontSize2);
}          

@end
```

Anyone ?

Comment: You should never, ever call -viewDidLoad yourself. *Especially* from within methods like -viewWillAppear:

Comment: thank you for your response...i removed the call...what do you think could be wrong :S I'm really helpless now

Comment: The SQLite rowid is not necessarily going to be the same as the row number in the table, especially after you start deleting rows. If Name can be unique, use that for your where clause, if not, you'll need to track the db rowid for each Name item in your data structure that's backing the table view.

Comment: you are right and i did take notice of it and actually didn't use the row id while deleting...i tried to use it before and got to what you are saying so in this code there is no use for the row number only by cell content

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of waisted time!!! the only simplest solution was to add in FavReal.m , in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method, in the @finally , ***sqlite3_finalize(stmt)***.
That was the whole problem!